# Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application from ListFragment

Tags: android

I have this ListActivity that is populated by json data from web server, but suddenly I want to try to use ViewPager on my app.

It seems like ListActivity and ListFragment has almost the same function. So what I did was to copy-paste the codes to ListFragment, I've change a little bit of code to get rid of errors though.

What I did was to put all the codes from onCreate(ListActivity) to onCreateView(ListFragment) like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);
    examinationList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ListView lv = getListView();
    new GetContacts().execute();

    return rootView;
}
```

That created an Content view not yet created exception. So what I did was create an onViewCreated method and remove all the unnecessary codes from onCreateView and transfer it to onViewCreated

```
@Override 
public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    examinationList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ListView lv = getListView();
    new GetContacts().execute();

}
```

that removed the Content view not yet created exception but now another exception appeared and I can't solve it.

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

**EDITED**

fragment_movies.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Main ListView 
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
    -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: maybe u shud do that in onActivityCreated method instead of onViewCreated

Comment: I've tried adding it on onActivityCreated method and it still giving me the same exception.

Comment: did you try commenting the new GetContacts().execute();?

Comment: It still gives the same exception unless I comment out it with ListView lv = getListView();

Comment: can you post your fragment_movies layout as well?

Comment: @AndroSelva I've already edited my question please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Solve it! The problem was on the showing of the ProgressDialog on onPreExecute, it seems like getting the context on normal activity is different from getting the context on fragments.